# How do I set up pypi to trusted?

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

I am trying to use Python wheels. When I do `pip install wheel`, it says that the requirement is there, however I get this SSL error:

```
(base) C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\prepay_clone>pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.33.1)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

At first I ignored it, since the wheel seems installed. However, when I later run `setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, it doesn't output absolutely anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the `--trusted-host` flag tells pip not to bother with SSL for the specified host. I have this problem all the time on a corporate network. I've found this to work 99% of the time:

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install wheel
```

I'm not sure if this is your problem though, pip seems to be telling you that wheel is already installed.

Comment: @deblue great, glad I was able to help. If this answers your question, could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!